# I am getting this error while extracting text from elements. Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to scrape amazon for product prices over multiple pages using selenium. I am able to get all the elements for product names and product prices but while extracting the text out of it Selenium throws up an error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from openpyxl import Workbook
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\varun\OneDrive\Documents\python projects\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.amazon.in/'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']").send_keys("oppo mobile")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Go']").click()
brand = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text() = 'Oppo']")))
brand.click()
ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='a-pagination']/li[6]")

url_list = []
products_list = []
prices_list = []


for page in range(int(ele.text)):
    page_ = page+1
    url_list.append(driver.current_url)
    prod_name_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']")
    prod_prices_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='a-price-whole']")
    driver.implicitly_wait(4)
    products_list = products_list + prod_name_list
    prices_list = prices_list + prod_prices_list
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='a-last']").click()
        print("page " + str(page_) + " is grabbed.")
        print(driver.current_url)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("All pages are collected!")
    time.sleep(5)

print("---------------------------------------------------")
print(products_list)
print("---------------------------------------------------")
print(prices_list)

product_name = []
prices = []

for product in products_list:
    product_name.append(product.text)
for price in prices_list:
    prices.append(price.text)


print(product_name)
print(prices)
```

Error message occurs at this line:

```
for product in products_list:
    product_name.append(product.text)
for price in prices_list:
    prices.append(price.text)
```

I tried slowing down scraping by putting implicit waits then too that error pops up. PLease help me with this error.
ThankYOU!

Comment: You should be appending the text in the previous for loop. If you indent your for loops so that they are apart of the previous loop it will work.

Comment: Yes it worked!!!...THANKYOU!! @ArundeepChohan

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(4) is something you only set once.

Comment: sorry?..I did not get you.@ArundeepChohan

Comment: It's something you don't need to set in the loop you can bring it out.

Comment: I have used only one impnicit wait

Comment: ohhkayyy!!!!...THANKS!!!

Comment: Once you set the ImplicitWait, the WebDriver instance i.e. the driver is able to carry this configuration till its lifetime. Meaning if you don't close it will always poll the DOM for the specified time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to not rely on Selenium's waits. Convert this Java method to a python one instead:

```
public static Boolean isVisibleInViewport(WebElement element) {
          WebDriver driver = ((RemoteWebElement)element).getWrappedDriver();

          return (Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
              "var elem = arguments[0],                 " +
              "  box = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),    " +
              "  cx = box.left + box.width / 2,         " +
              "  cy = box.top + box.height / 2,         " +
              "  e = document.elementFromPoint(cx, cy); " +
              "for (; e; e = e.parentElement) {         " +
              "  if (e === elem)                        " +
              "    return true;                         " +
              "}                                        " +
              "return false;                            "
              , element);
        }
```

(Just three lines of code to edit). This JS function just *really* checks for the element to be visible to the user in the viewport, i've always used it, one of the best functions circulating. No more tedious waits.